# Difference between numpy ediff1d and diff

Tags: python, numpy

I have recently discovered [`numpy.ediff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html)
Is there an advantage of using [`numpy.ediff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html) instead of [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) or what is it's usecase?

Comment: From the docs, the Notes of `ediff1d` gives some info on how it operates on boolean arrays, which might be the difference.

Comment: ediff1d performs similar functionality to a flattened array first order difference...  a[1:] - a[:-1] with padding the output array at the start and/or end  ediff1d(ary, to_end=None, to_begin=None)  whereas diff allows calculating more than a 1st order difference and  you can specify the dimension of the array for the calculation...  try... np.diff(x, n=1) -> array([ 1,  2,  3, -7]) whereas  ... np.ediff1d(x, to_begin=-99, to_end=-98) yields ->
array([-99,   1,   2,   3,  -7, -98])

Comment: @DanPatterson So in principal `diff` is superiour but misses padding.

Answer (score 5):

Prior to `numpy 1.16.0`, one could use `ediff1d(ar, to_end, to_begin)` to pad the result of `ar[1:] - ar[-1:]`. But from `1.16.0` `diff()` supports padding and covers all of `ediff1d()` functionality and much more. Also, `diff()` has same performance in most cases and outperforms `ediff1d()` for boolean arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Another `diff`erence is that `diff`'s `prepend` and `append` arguments apply BEFORE the difference calculation whereas `ediff1d`'s `to_begin` and `to_end` apply AFTER the difference calculation (and thus are NOT similar arguments).